# Javascript MDN Function prototype bind polyfill is enumerable in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a project in which I have created a jQuery plugin and various other js files that use bind() in various places.
The client requested IE8 support out of the blue, so we included some function polyfills to support ie8
but in IE8 in loops like the following the methods are enumerable which causes data corruption.

```
for (var d in this.originalResponse.timespans) {}
```

In particular our issue is regarding bind() and here is the mdn polyfill we are using

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

The result of an iteration will give out an extra iteration with the bind prototype which is unwanted.
Is there a way to support the bind method on IE8 without being enumerable?

**UPDATE:**

`this.originalResponse.timespans` structure is an object in which the key is a unix timestamp and the value is an array of strings. When I tried to loop through this I was getting an extra iteration because the polyfill (for reason unknown to me) was creating a function prototype inside the object which was enumerable.

**UPDATE 2**

the data are being received from an ajax / json call, this is a sample data structure from the server:

```
{  
   "timespans":[  
      {  
         "1417685819":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "1417772219":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "1417858619":[  

         ]
      }
   ],
   "start":"7:00",
   "current":"11:36",
   "end":"23:00"
}
```

and after receiving these data for the sake of simplicity I transform the data structure like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.success = function( r ) {

    var response = {
        timespans:{}
    };

    response.start = r.start;
    response.end = r.end;
    response.current = r.current;

    for (var t in r.timespans) 
    {

        for (var tt in r.timespans[t])
        {
            response.timespans[tt] = r.timespans[t][tt];
        }
    }  

    var that = this;
    this.originalResponse = response;
    // other code doing some calculation based on this.originalResponse;


 }
```

Comment: `this.originalResponse.timespans` is a function? Why do you enumerate it?

Comment: @Bergi I guess some data are stored on it, since function is also an object. This trick is somehow popular in functional programming.

Comment: @LeoDeng: But there you usually know what data you are dealing with, not deeding to enumerate it. My guess is that OP is doing something horribly wrong. He also talks about an array, but I can't see any.

Comment: @Bergi Yep you are right, to enumerate a function is weird.

Comment: Could you describe your use case? Let's see if we can figure out a better solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay question is updated

Comment: You're right, if it is a plain object then the enumeration should not happen. What is the value of `this.originalRespone.timespans.bind`? How is the `timespans` object created? Please provide [some code that lets us reproduce the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question updated sorry for the delay once again

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting old browsers that doesn't support `Object.defineProperty`, then I'm afraid it's not possible.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'bind', {
        value: function() {
            // function body here
        }
    });
}
```

Using `Object.defineProperty`, by default the property/method is not enumerable (won't show up in enumeration), not configurable (can't be deleted), and not writable (can't be overwritten).

See [**doc on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more info.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing out this. Answer updated. It seems for IE8 that's not possible.